# why constructors are not necessary for primitive types?

Tags: java, oop, object, primitive-types

I am looking for an answer to the questions

1. why constructors are not necessary for primitive types in java?
2. is it because primitive types do not need to be built before use?

Comment: What is the purpose of a constructor?

Comment: Constructors initialise the member fields of Objects. Primitives types are not Objects and do not have members.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Assignments and tests aren't usually arbitrary; your instructor, tutorial, or course will have covered this material if they're asking you this question. **Review your course materials, class notes, etc.** *If* you run into a *specific* problem, research it thoroughly, [search thoroughly here](/help/searching), and if you're still stuck post your code and a description of the problem. People will be glad to help. *(not my dv)*

Comment: A constructor is executed upon instance creation. Primitive types are not instances but just values.

Answer (score 1):

First, you must understand that **primitive types are not objects**. They've been made to help C users switch to Java. Also, primitive types do not store any instance variables like objects do, but are rather values themselves.
It's also worth noting that you also don't need to call constructor of any class that extends interface Number (Integer, Double, Long, etc.).
There are some gotchas in Java that sometimes make it feel like it's not entirely like that, but you should mostly be fine using ethier primitive types or objects in java (except for, that primitive types don't have any methods, so you will need to turn `int` into `Integer` with `Integer.valueOf(n)` before you will be able to, for example, call `toString()`)

Comment: I'm not sure that's the reason that primitives exist in Java.

Answer (score 0):

a constructor is a special method wich purpose is to create a new instance of and object, since primitive data types are not objects they don't have a constructor or methods associated to them.

However Java has primitive wrapper class for some primitive datatypes.

[image]

the wrapper class are very useful in the case of the Integer class you can use methods like parseInt(String s), toBinaryString(int i), or to do some operations over a Integer object

i.e:

```
Integer i = new Integer(7);
byte b = i.byteValue();
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Primitive types

Declaring a primitive type e.g. `int i;` you can see that it is already in life (i.e. the space in memory is already taken),even if it doesn't have a value assigned i.e. even if it is not defined.

#### Objects

First of all, an object is a abstract concept consisting of state,behaviour and identity.

- **State**: information *encapsuled* in the object
- **Behaviour**: defined by method written within the class of which the object is *instance*
- **Identity**: despite from primitive types that are equal if they have the same value, two objects are not the same object neither if they have the same state, i.e. if they encapsulate the same information.

So to give life to an object, declaration is not enough, it needs also the definition i.e. the call to **a** costructor.
The indefinite article is important: in fact *an object can have many different costructors with different signatures*, providing different ways to initialize it. So, different costuctors lead to differents state and behaviours, and this the reason why an object needs to be built.